# Checking whether a server is up or not using batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I need to check whether a server is up or not?
If down then i need to send an email
And this task should be repeated in every 30mins.

I have to do this using batch file.

Comment: By "server is up" do you mean the physical or virtual machine is powered on and responding to network requests or something else like a web server or application server is running?

Comment: Both the things. Either physically or responding to network requests

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This batch file will get you most of the way there.  You'll have to use blat or something similar or Windows script to send the email.  Use the task scheduler to call the batch file every 30 minutes.

checkserver.bat:

```
@echo off
ping -n 1 %1 > NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (echo "Up -- Don't send email.") ELSE echo "Down -- Send email."
```

Call it like so:

```
C:\>checkserver 127.0.0.1  
"Up -- Don't send email."

C:\>checkserver 128.0.0.1  
"Down -- Send email."
```

Comment: Thanx a lot. Can you suggest me some way to check whether an application server is up or not. I mean checking an http request like http ://IP:9001?

Comment: `%errorlevel%` doesn't work with `ping` . When you get `Reply from ... host unreachable` the `%errorlevel%` is still 0.

Comment: Wow, this post is like 10 years old. Anyway, what I posted worked back then for what this person asked or I wouldn't have posted this response. I don't know if it still works. Regardless, this person wasn't asking about dealing with Host Unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access one of its filesystem shares or ping it if you know its IP address. That would be the easiest way and both of them doable from CMD.

Comment: I know the IP and I can ping as well but how would I get to know that the ping is successful?

Answer (score 0):

To check whether server is up, you can use the `ping` command. To send email, you can download email tools like `blat` etc. To repeat every 30mins, set it up using task scheduler.

Comment: if ping got successful then how would I identify it?

Comment: Does ping return some boolean value of something?

Comment: Do a ping manually on the command line, then check its %errorlevel%.

Comment: Can you suggest that how can I test an http request or some application server is up e.g. http ://IP:9001/

Answer (score -1):

You can check whether the machine replies to `ping`. But because ping on Windows doesn't return a useful `%errorlevel%`, you need to pipe it's output through `find`.

Example:

```
ping -4 -n 2 YourIPorHostname | find "TTL=" >NUL && echo OK
```

or

```
ping -4 -n 2 YourIPorHostname | find "TTL=" >NUL || echo No reply
```

To send an email, you need some additional program.

(if you also have a Unix machine on your network, the whole thing would be much easier from there, since the "crontab" scheduler automatically sends emails)